# Standardization or Feature Scaling?

Tags: dataset, normalization, standardization

I downloaded the 2013 dataset from [Kyoto University](http://www.takakura.com/Kyoto_data/ext_old_data201704/).

My question is this: **how will I know if I should *[feature] scale* or *standardize* my data?**.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE 07/13/2017a**

[This](https://github.com/AFAgarap/gru-svm/blob/master/dataset/pandas-describe.py) is the script I wrote for getting the data summary using `pandas`.

**UPDATE 07/13/2017b**

Here's the data summary, with description of index `[22]`:

```
                 0             2             3             4             5   \
count  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06   
mean   5.629711e+00  7.620859e+03  8.519262e+03  1.819146e+00  2.604244e-01   
std    1.747110e+02  3.446973e+06  3.346247e+06  8.298907e+00  4.228922e-01   
min    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00   
25%    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00   
50%    2.866777e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00   
75%    3.419435e+00  1.280000e+02  2.090000e+02  1.000000e+00  5.000000e-01   
max    8.097288e+04  2.133443e+09  2.116371e+09  1.000000e+02  1.000000e+00   

             6             7             8             9             10  \
count  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06   
mean   5.863585e-02  4.008782e-01  1.056284e+01  2.819324e+01  3.256177e-02   
std    2.289534e-01  4.238607e-01  2.233580e+01  2.824031e+01  1.718919e-01   
min    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00   
25%    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00   
50%    0.000000e+00  3.300000e-01  0.000000e+00  3.000000e+01  0.000000e+00   
75%    0.000000e+00  9.500000e-01  5.000000e+00  5.000000e+01  0.000000e+00   
max    1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+02  1.000000e+02  1.000000e+00   

             11            12            17            19            21  \
count  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06  4.656124e+06   
mean   1.405558e-01  2.122936e-01 -3.552655e-01  2.292569e+04  1.648552e+03   
std    3.280353e-01  3.864984e-01  9.440645e-01  2.250753e+04  6.820971e+03   
min    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -2.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00   
25%    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00  3.028000e+03  2.500000e+01   
50%    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00  6.000000e+03  8.000000e+01   
75%    0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  4.522200e+04  4.450000e+02   
max    1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  6.553500e+04  6.553500e+04   

             22  
count  4.656124e+06  
mean   1.216933e+01  
std    7.080260e+00  
min    0.000000e+00  
25%    5.916667e+00  
50%    1.228806e+01  
75%    1.844000e+01  
max    2.399944e+01
```

**UPDATE 07/19/2017**

I finished writing the final script for standardizing my dataset, and [here it is](https://github.com/AFAgarap/gru-svm/blob/master/dataset/normalize_data.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standardization (or normalization using Student's t statistics, to use a longer name) is a good practice if you don't want your machine learning algorithm to improperly assign a larger relevance to the variable that has the largest variability in absolute terms, and sometimes just for easier interpretation of the machine learning algorithm parameters. That being said, some algorithms strictly require standardization (es Principal Component Analysis) and some other do not at all (Random Forests).

In order to reply to your problem, you should provide some summary of data to understand the numerical range. If you are using python+pandas, that would be `df.describe()`, in R, that would be `summary(df)`. You should standardize the variables that are continuous, or quasi continuous (integers over a wide range). In your case, from what I see you should standardize the duration, bytes, counts and error rates.

You are free to normalize the same variables instead of standardizing them, but it would not make sense to standardize some and normalize others.

Comment: A novice question -- so, it's okay to standardize just those that you mentioned, and leave the other features to normalization? In addition, should I normalize after after standardizing those features?

Comment: Perhaps confusion here is just about naming convention. What I am suggesting is to "normalize according to standard score" as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics). In other words, subtract the mean and divide by standard deviation. I don't see how you could do normalization using any kind of score (at least the ones I know) when the variable is a MAC address - or any categorical variable for that matter.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot that for the experiment, I will be disregarding the IP Address features first. I'll just get back on it if I get to read a method on transforming their values as well.

Comment: In regards with the naming convention, yeah. I got that a bit wrong. My question should have been, for other features, should I just do feature scaling instead of standardizing?

Comment: I don't think your word usage is wrong. I used the word *standardize* to mean *normalize according to standard score* (or better using *Student's t statistics*, given that I assume you don't know mean and standard deviation, nor if distribution is gaussian), and you used *normalize* to mean *normalize using unity-based normalization* or simply *feature scaling*. Regardless, using different normalizations  metrics in the same data would not make sense to me. And I prefer using Student's t statistic as it uses the information on how observations spread in your data through the standard error.

Comment: So, I should just leave other features as they are? Just standardize the features you've mentioned?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the few lines you showed me are not sufficient to see what variables are continous (or quasi-continous). The only way for me to judge would be to use the pandas describe/R summary option to see how values are distributed for each variable. The ones I mentioned are the ones I *expect* to be continous, and that seems to be confirmed by the little data you are sharing here.

Comment: Does that mean I have to describe the whole dataset (16.2 GB) using pandas describe? Or just a portion of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62075/discussion-between-famargar-and-abien-fred-agarap).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you say that PCA requires standardization? Wouldn't that be something like taking the eigendecomposition of the correlation matrix?